# Meteor ddp-client.js socksjs ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on local

Tags: meteor, sockjs

#### The problem

I'm having an issue where when I start my local dev server with `meteor`, about 3/5 times the client's socksjs connection via `ddp-client.js` isn't able to connect and gets an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. All other connections work fine (websocket, JS, css, etc).

I'm seeing this in the console
[image]

The socks is attempting to connect to `192.168.1.14`, which is my correct internal ip.

#### What I've tried

- setting the port manually with `meteor --port 3000`
- waiting for `Meteor.status().status === 'connected'` on the client before making any calls

If you'd like to recreate the problem yourself you can pull down the package I'm working on, [ProseMeteor](https://github.com/prosemeteor/prosemirror) at commit 51c0a304338228102edc75427f72e689a7aafb8a and try running the app yourself by running the `bash run_demo` script, you should see the problem when you visit `http://localhost:3000`.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you connecting to a remote server? If not, then why use local network ip address instead of `localhost`?

Comment: Nope this is just on my local. I haven't configured it to point to my internal ip though, the Meteor framework sets up the socksjs connection and automatically points it to it

Comment: That's weird. Is this happening on windows?

Comment: Not sure, I can check in a few hours on Windows and Linux and report back. This was seen on OSX

Comment: Yes it happens on Windows as well, I imagine it's either an issue with Meteor or with how the demo application is set up but it's been built like any normal Meteor app.